# PHP - compare two variables

Tags: php, string, compare

I have this code

```
<?php

ob_start();
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");

$campo = $_GET['campo'];
$valor = $_GET['valor'];
$hello;

    if ($campo == "myPassword") {
        if (!preg_match("/^\S{4,12}$/", $valor)) {
            echo "Tamanho entre 4 e 12 letras e sem espaços";
        }
        else 
            $hello = $valor; //problem here
            echo $hello;
    }

if ($campo == "passwordMatch") {
    if ($hello != $valor ) {
        echo "Passwords don't match";
    }
}
```

?>

so, i need to save a variable (where i put "problem here") and compare below, but this code didn't work and i don't know why

Comment: Define "this code didn't work".

Comment: care to expand on "didn't work"

Comment: What kind of problem are you seeing? Is `$hello` a blank string, or do you get PHP exceptions/errors? Try a `var_dump($_GET);` to ensure you are receiving data if the problem is that `$hello` is blank.

Comment: i need to save the variable $hello to compare above if the pass match with the field above. It is a temporarily save when the user do a new registry. At the moment echo of $hello in the first if show the pass but in the second the echo of $hello is nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using to compare strings reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

```
if(strcmp($str1,$str2)):
endif;
```

or

```
if(!strcmp($str1,$str2)):
endif;
```

and replace your code with this

```
if (!preg_match("/^\S{4,12}$/", $valor)) {
            echo "Tamanho entre 4 e 12 letras e sem espaços";
        }
        else {
            $hello = $valor; //problem here
            echo $hello;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turned out to be white space, I used `trim($myVar);` to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting `$hello` to survive between page loads, you're out of luck.

Instead you'll need to persist the variable between [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) yourself.

*BTW, the line `$hello;` doesn't do anything.*

**Edit** The reason I have assumed that you need sessions is that you set `$hello` only when `$campo == "newPassword"`, then later expect it to be a certain value only when `$campo == "passwordMatch"`. You never change the value of `$campo`, and clearly it can't be both. This implies that the two pieces of logic are to run on separate page loads.

Comment: what i want is a simple comparison when the user do a new registry.

Comment: @Fel: What is a "new registry"? How do you know that your required solution is "simple" when you don't know what it is? Please read up on sessions as advised above, and decide whether you need that in your code. Also, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a syntax issue here:

```
if ($campo == "myPassword") {
        if (!preg_match("/^\S{4,12}$/", $valor)) {
            echo "Tamanho entre 4 e 12 letras e sem espaços";
        } else {  // missing bracket
            $hello = $valor; //problem here
            echo $hello;
            } // missing bracket
    }
```

Is that your problem? Your `ELSE` was missing an opening `{` and closing `}`.

**ALSO**

For string comparison, you should use `===` and not a numerical `==`

Details are here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php